# How do I use Promise.all() with chrome.storage()?

Tags: asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, es6-promise, google-chrome-storage

I have several async functions running. I want to wait for them all to finish before taking the next steps. Here's my code that I'm using to get all of the key/values from `chrome.storage` and the `Promise.all()` implementation.

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

var getAll = chrome.storage.sync.get(function(result) {
  console.log(result)
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3, getAll]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values); // [3, 42, "foo", undefined]
});
```

This doesn't work unfortunately. It returns `undefined`.

Most of the code above is taken from MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: chrome.storage.sync.get doesn't return anything as you can see in the documentation. The simplest solution is to use Mozilla WebExtension polyfill.

Comment: FWIW, this should be coming to Chrome finally:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=328932

Answer (score 13):

The `chrome.*` API does not support promises, it uses async callbacks.

But you can promisify your call to `chrome.storage.sync.get`:

```js
var getAllPromise = (function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(function(result) {
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
})();

Promise.all([getAllPromise]).then(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of July 29, 2022, according to [chrome.storage documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#asynchronous-preload-from-storage), it seems the `chrome.storage` API (manifest V3) still does not use promises with `get` and `set` calls (note the "pending" status of their Promise-based return types). However, that documentation does show how to promisify their code **including error handling**. (I would have just linked to this in a comment but I don't have the rep)

```js
function getAllStorageSyncData() {
    // Immediately return a promise and start asynchronous work
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Asynchronously fetch all data from storage.sync.
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, (items) => {
        // Pass any observed errors down the promise chain.
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        return reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        }
        // Pass the data retrieved from storage down the promise chain.
        resolve(items);
    });
    });
}
```

Note the part with `chrome.runtime.lastError` that returns via the promise's `reject` callback.